# JQuery Polling using MySQL and PHP. How?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have found various ways to poll MySQL on the site both good and bad and mostly 2 years old.

I would like to see an example of how to properly poll a server.

I have a MySQL table where comments are inserted. I'd like to see an example in JQuery on how to poll this server and append to a DIV, only the new comments inserted in a table since the last polling check instead of displaying the last 10 entries every 5 seconds.

A non setInterval example would be ideal as I've read setInterval does not care if request was successful before making another request.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send a AJAX request to a server side script that would check for new comments in the DB and return them JSON encoded.

To get only the latest comments, on the client side code, maintain a timestamp of the last comment fetch. Next time you request comments, pass this timestamp. Your server side script will only return comments with a timestamp grater than the passed in paramter.

Instead of using `setInterval`, you can resubmit the AJAX request in the success handler.

```
function ajaxRequest(timestamp) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'url_to_post?timestamp=' + timestamp,
        success : function(response){
            //handle the new comments here
            //call this function again
            //sleep for 3 seconds first
            setTimeout(function(){
                timestamp += 3000;
                ajaxRequest(timestamp);
            },3000);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. Can you tell me more about resubmitting the AJAX request in the success handler? Sounds like some sort of a loop. Or perhaps post a sample? =)

Comment: @Vini: I've posted a code sample. Yes, it is a recursive loop.

Comment: Right on. As for making sure the timestamp format submitted, stored and retrieved from MySQL through PHP are the same so that they can be compared, hopefully all 3 languages can easily translate into each other.

Comment: alternatively, you can have the server delay up to 50 seconds before sending a response, then have the success handler immediately send another AJAX request. This way you can have the server respond quicker if it has something to report, giving you snappier performance with less requests.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.